# Exportar fopen sem as ""

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Estou  usando o `fopen` , para exportar o retorno de um select, ele esta exportando corretamente, mais em certos campos esta aparecendo `""` como eu removo as `""` da exportacao, deixando somente a `,`

> porque esta saindo da seguinte forma:  "arroz","batata doce"
>
> preciso que saia: arroz,batata doce...

```
  <?php 
  require('data/conexao.php');

  $periodo = $_GET['folheto'];

  $data = date("Ymd");
  $hora = date("His");
  $nomeExport = "exportacao-".$data;
  $paginaAtual = "";
  $limite = 24;
  $conta = 0;
  $export = $conn->prepare("SELECT 
    f.prod_folheto_produto AS produto,
    f.prod_folheto_marca   AS marca,
    f.prod_folheto_tipo1   AS descricao,
    f.prod_folheto_tipo2   AS subdescricao,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.prod_folheto_preco,'.',1) AS preco,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.prod_folheto_preco,'.',-1) AS centavos,
    REPLACE(f.prod_folheto_gramatura,',','.') AS gramatura,  
    (CASE 
    WHEN f.prod_folheto_pais = 0 THEN 'BRA' ELSE   p.iso3
    END) AS pais,
    prod_folheto_pagina AS pagina
    FROM 
    produto_folheto AS f
    LEFT JOIN cep_paises AS p
    ON p.numcode = f.prod_folheto_pais
    WHERE
    prod_folheto_periodo = '$periodo'
    ORDER BY prod_folheto_pagina ASC");
  $export->execute(array());


  $paginaAtual = "";
  $limite = 24;
  $conta = 0;

  $novoArr = array();

  while($dados = $export->fetch()){

    if($paginaAtual ==""){ 

      $paginaAtual = $dados["pagina"];

      $conta = 0;

    }elseif($paginaAtual != $dados['pagina']){

     while($conta < $limite){ 

       $novoArr[] = "-,-,-,-,-,-,-";

       $conta++;
     }

     $paginaAtual = $dados["pagina"];

     $conta = 0;
   }
   $conta++;

   $novoArr[] = 
   $dados["produto"]      .","
   .$dados["marca"]        .","
   .$dados["descricao"]    .","
   .$dados["subdescricao"] .","
   .$dados["preco"]        .","
   .$dados["centavos"]     .","
   .$dados["gramatura"]    .",";
 }
 while($conta < $limite){

  $novoArr[] = "-,-,-,-,-,-,-";

  $conta++;


}

$file = fopen("export/$nomeExport.csv","w");

fprintf($file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));

fputcsv($file, array('produto','marca','descricao','subdescricao','preco','centavos','gramatura'));

foreach ($novoArr as $line)
{
  fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
}

fclose($file); 

?>
```

O que notei é que as `""` aparecem quando tem duas palavras juntas, exemplo: `"batata doce"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fputcsv**

(PHP 5 >= 5.1.0, PHP 7)

fputcsv — Formata a linha como CSV e a escreve em um ponteiro de arquivo

Parâmetros

- **handle**: O ponteiro de arquivo precisa ser válido, e apontar para um arquivo aberto por `fopen()` ou `fsockopen()` (e ainda não fechado por `fclose()`).
- **fields**: Um *array* de valores.
- **delimiter**: O parâmetro opcional *delimiter* configura o caractere delimitador (apenas um caractere).
- **enclosure**: O parâmetro opcional *enclosure* configura o caractere que envolve os dados (apenas um caractere).
- **escape_char**: O parâmetro opcional *escape_char* configura o caractere de escape (apenas um caractere).

Sua função ficaria assim:

```
fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line), ",", ' ');
```

ou assim:

```
fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line), ",", chr(32));
```

referência

[php.net/fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Coloquei a referência na resposta.